# Cordova and Android global path

Tags: android, cordova, path

I have installed the command line tools for phonegap. Now I am trying to get cordova and android to talk but now I am getting this error:

/root/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.1/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
     Error: ERROR : executing command 'ant', make sure you have ant installed and added to your path.

I figure it may have something to do with global path. I have tried doing some study on the mattter but cant seem to lock it down and getting it to work. Can some one assist or point me in the right direction? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error clearly states that the `Ant` software is not installed. You need to install `Ant` and other softwares to start working on Cordova/PhoneGap.
You also need to set a few `ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES`

Have a look over [here](http://thejackalofjavascript.com/phonegap-3-cli-setup-mac-windows/) for setting up cordova/phonegap on MAC and Windows.